# Losing zoom/pan when changing SVG source

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, svg, svgpanzoom

I'm using svg-pan-zoom (https://github.com/ariutta/svg-pan-zoom/) in order to display SVG in my angularJS page :

```
<object id="svgElement" type="image/svg+xml" data="../SVG/{{currentLanguage}}/{{currentCartography}}.svg">
It seems your browser doesn't support SVG.
</object>

<script>
    window.onload = function() {
        document.getElementById("svgElement").style.width = window.screen.availWidth + "px";
        document.getElementById("svgElement").style.height = window.screen.availHeight + "px"; // This seems to include the browser bar :(
        svgPanZoom('#svgElement', {
            zoomEnabled: true,
            controlIconsEnabled: true,
            fit: true,
            center: true,
            minZoom: 0.75,
            maxZoom: 50,
            zoomScaleSensitivity: 0.25,
            dblClickZoomEnabled: true
        });
    };
</script>
```

Depending on some events, I want to change the displayed SVG, so after clicking some elements, I'm calling a `changeSVG(fileName)` function :

```
    <a href="#" onclick="changeSVG('map1')">map1</a><br />
    <a href="#" onclick="changeSVG('map2')">map2</a><br />
    <a href="#" onclick="changeSVG('map3')">map3</a><br />
    <a href="#" onclick="changeSVG('tiger')">tiger</a><br />
```

The SVG is changed and dislayed but :
I lose the Zoom and Pan feature.

I get the zoom and pan feature back if I click again on the same element.
In the end, in order to change the displayed SVG and keep the zoom/pan features, I need to click 2 times instead of one.
Calling the function 2 times instead of one after one click isn't solving the issue.

My changeSVG function :

```
$scope.changeSVG = function (fileName) {
    svgPanZoom('#svgElement').destroy();
    $scope.currentCartography = fileName;
    document.getElementById("svgElement").style.width = window.screen.availWidth + "px";
    document.getElementById("svgElement").style.height = window.screen.availHeight + "px"; // This seems to include the browser bar :(
    svgPanZoom('#svgElement', {
        zoomEnabled: true,
        controlIconsEnabled: true,
        fit: true,
        center: true,
        minZoom: 0.75,
        maxZoom: 50,
        zoomScaleSensitivity: 0.25,
        dblClickZoomEnabled: true
    });
}
```

EDIT : I tried this for the test but with it it doesnt even load the pan-zoom at all, even after 2 clicks :

```
    $scope.changeSVG = function (fileName) {
        var svgData = "../SVG/" + $scope.currentLanguage + "/" + fileName + ".svg";
       /* document.getElementById("svgElement").setAttribute("data", svgData);*/
        $scope.currentCartography = fileName;
        svgPanZoom('#svgElement').destroy();
        var oldE = document.getElementById("svgElement");
        document.getElementById("svgElement").parentElement.removeChild(oldE);
        var newE = document.createElement("object");
        newE.setAttribute("type", "image/svg+xml");
        newE.setAttribute("id", "svgElement");
        newE.setAttribute("style", "width: " + window.screen.availWidth + "px; height: " + window.screen.availHeight + "px;");
        newE.setAttribute("data", svgData);
        var nextE = document.getElementById("afterSVG");
        document.body.insertBefore(newE, nextE);
/*
        document.getElementById("svgElement").style.width = window.screen.availWidth + "px";
        document.getElementById("svgElement").style.height = window.screen.availHeight + "px";
*/
       // alert(document.getElementById("svgElement").getAttribute("data"));
        svgPanZoom('#svgElement', {
            zoomEnabled: true,
            controlIconsEnabled: true,
            fit: true,
            center: true,
            minZoom: 0.75,
            maxZoom: 50,
            zoomScaleSensitivity: 0.25,
            dblClickZoomEnabled: true
        });
    }
```

EDIT 2 :

You can see it on plunker here : http://embed.plnkr.co/0nufcYZpE3ZzGxKQmUkf/preview
we need to be in embedded to make it work properly (full width issue I'm guessing).
Bring your mouse on the left to spawn the menu, and you'll see we need to click twice on an element to reactivate the pan/zoom.

Comment: It may be so that `currentCartography` gets applied to the element after your `changeSVG` function is done because that's when Angularjs digest cycle will perform the checks. So before calling `svgPanZoom` you should be sure that object data attribute got updated. To do so you may reinitialize `svgPanZoom` by watching currentCartography, or by changing object data directly (so to be sure that it changed).

Comment: You also should take into account that you're loading a remote SVG element and if you'll call `svgPanZoom` before SVG loaded - you can have some problems too.

Comment: Well, I tried this : `document.getElementById("svgElement").setAttribute("data", svgData);` before my svgPanZoom call. I checked and my data is up to date. But still the same. The SVG is changed and displayed. But Can't zoom and pan anymore.

Comment: How do you check that `data` attribute is changed before `svgPanZoom` call? Just assigning `$scope.currentCartography = fileName` doesn't mean that the HTML is updated instantly.

Comment: Well it is true my data was updated only after the second click. So I tried to add in my changeSVG function, before the svgPanZoom() call :
`document.getElementById("svgElement").setAttribute("data", fileName);`
and to check `alert(document.getElementById("svgElement").getAttribute("data"));`.
I also edited my post to show a few other things I tried.
Then, the data was up to date. But I still don't have the zoom/pan/controlIcons nutil I click a second time.

Comment: Can you please set-up an example on jsfiddle so I can play with it. It is hard to guess what exactly is your problem.

Comment: Ok, so I didn't manage to make it work at all on jsFiddle. Some troubles with controller binding or idk. But i put it on Koding.
You can use it at : http://uekk77989bfe.ellone.koding.io/Viewer/src/test.html : Put your mouse cursor on the left of the screen to display the menu and elements to click to change SVG.
And you can see and get the few sources at : http://uekk77989bfe.ellone.koding.io/Viewer/src/ but the only file u might need to see is probably http://uekk77989bfe.ellone.koding.io/Viewer/src/controllers/viewerController.js

Comment: Sorry, but it gives an error for me. `svg-pan-zoom.js:367 Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`. And I don't have time to debug your example. If you can provide an example on jsfiddle (or a similar service) where I can easily change code - I'll look into helping you.

Comment: It's weird, it's the exact error I had with my full project on createSVGMatrix() that I posted on the git issues. But for me it was only with Chrome. Di you have the same error with any browser ? (But it's working even on Chrome with this url for me)
I'll try to make it work on Fiddle anyway.

Comment: Ok, so I managed to make it work on plunker. But only in embedded view. So from the original splitted view mode, we need to click on 'open the embedded view' (third icon top right), I think it might be because of some resolution issues since I'm using the full window.
Anyway, here is the direct link : http://embed.plnkr.co/0nufcYZpE3ZzGxKQmUkf/preview
As I said before, put your mouse on the left to make the menu appear then use it to navigate between SVG, and you'll notice we need to click twice to properly change the svg.

Comment: More likely, the issue comes from angular.
More info here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30051962/scope-updated-but-not-html