# HTML object data not updated while scope is

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, svg, svgpanzoom

Using AngularJS and svg-pan-zoom, I display external svg using an `<object>` as follows :

```
<object ng-show="currentCartography" id="svgElement" type="image/svg+xml" data="{{currentCartography}}.svg">
It seems your browser doesn't support SVG.
</object>
```

The issue is that when I change my svg using a function like this :

```
<a href="#" onclick="changeSVG('tiger')">Tiger</a><br />
<a href="#" onclick="changeSVG('Tux')">Tux</a><br />
```

Only the scope variable is updated. I have to click twice on the link to also update the `data` of the html `<object>`.

Here is the `changeSVG(fileName)` function :

Out of my controller :

```
// Out of the controller
function    changeSVG(fileName) {
   var scope = angular.element(document.getElementById("svgElement")).scope();

   scope.$apply(function() {
       scope.changeSVG(fileName);
   })
}
```

And in my controller :

```
// Inside controller
$scope.changeSVG = function (fileName) {
    console.log("HTML Object data before : " + document.getElementById("svgElement").getAttribute("data"));
    console.log("Scope currentCartography before : " + $scope.currentCartography + "\n--");
    $scope.currentCartography = fileName;
    window.panZoom.destroy();
    svgPanZoom('#svgElement').destroy();
    window.panZoom = svgPanZoom('#svgElement', {
        zoomEnabled: true,
        controlIconsEnabled: true,
        fit: true,
        center: true,
        minZoom: 0.75,
        maxZoom: 50,
        zoomScaleSensitivity: 0.25,
        dblClickZoomEnabled: true
    });
    console.log("HTML Object data after : " + document.getElementById("svgElement").getAttribute("data"));
    console.log("Scope currentCartography after : " + $scope.currentCartography + "\n-----");
};
```

I'm using the console to check some values and indeed, **the scope variable are updated when I call my function, but the `data` attribute of my html `<object>` is not until I click a second time**.
Any idea of what's going on ?
I want my html to be updated in one click, not two.

Here is a live example, click on the menu on the left to change SVG and see the behavior :
 http://embed.plnkr.co/0nufcYZpE3ZzGxKQmUkf/preview
(This might not work on IE)

Comment: your plunkr is working fine for me.. I only need to click once on the link to have image change

Comment: Yea, but you are losing the zoom and pan feature. And look at the console.

Comment: The zoom is working fine - both by mouse-scroll as well as 'plus' & 'minus' buttons. In the console I do see an exception:
`ReferenceError: openSearch is not defined`
This however happens only when I click on the magnifying-glass for search

Comment: Oh I see now.. Single click only loads the image but not the tool layer..

Comment: Yes and fom the console we can see that after one click, the scope variable is changed, but the data of the object stays the same, until we click a second time.